# Date in Kivy language

Tags: python, date, kivy

I am having a hard time getting Kivy's slider to recognize my date values.
Below is the code.

```
Slider:
    min: root.minimumdate()
    max: root.maximumdate()
    value: root.maximumdate()
    pos: root.width/200, root.height/1.159
    width: root.width/2.9
    height: root.height/10
```

Minimumdate and maximumdate functions return my lower and upper bound date values formatted as (YYYY-MM); however, kivy language does not seem to recognize the date values. Is there a date conversion I need to do before using it as slider values?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Slider accept integer values so you should convert your dates to some kind of numeric timestamp, for example:

```
import datetime
import time

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<MyWidget>
    Slider:
        id: slider
        min: root.minimumdate()
        max: root.maximumdate()
        on_value:
            date_label.text = root.timestamp_to_datetime(args[1]) 
    Label:
        text: root.timestamp_to_datetime(slider.value)
        id: date_label
''')

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    def minimumdate(self):
        d = datetime.datetime.now()
        return time.mktime(d.timetuple())

    def maximumdate(self):
        d = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        return time.mktime(d.timetuple())

    def timestamp_to_datetime(self, timestamp):
        return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
            int(timestamp)
        ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: This is awesome. It's unfortunate that date format isn't supported in its original form, but this will do. Thanks!